# Find multiple cells in a column, select cells from adjacent columns and call a module for each cell separately

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck in a rather awkward situation:
lets say I have a column full of consecutive days from year 2015 to 2017, column D.

First I would like to find every cell from that column that contains first day of the month.

Second I would like to select a cell on the same row and 2 columns away for each cell I find (column F).

Third I would like to call a module for each of these cells separately (since the module I developed relies on ActiveCell selection).

Lastly is it possible to take every single cell that corresponds to first day of the month (the one which had the module called on it) and autofill it all the way to the row containing the last day of the month?

```
Date         Week  Total Companytotal
23-03-15    29-mar  224 45
24-03-15    29-mar  251 37
25-03-15    29-mar  365 77
26-03-15    29-mar  404 147
27-03-15    29-mar  394 132
28-03-15    29-mar  514 123
29-03-15    29-mar  538 132
30-03-15    5-apr   472 122
31-03-15    5-apr   551 152
01-04-15    5-apr   730 163
02-04-15    5-apr   604 112
03-04-15    5-apr   511 129
04-04-15    5-apr   336 84
05-04-15    5-apr   298 98
06-04-15    12-apr  517 144
07-04-15    12-apr  507 121
08-04-15    12-apr  647 165
09-04-15    12-apr  646 181
10-04-15    12-apr  745 189
11-04-15    12-apr  643 168
12-04-15    12-apr  699 174
13-04-15    19-apr  698 174
14-04-15    19-apr  759 160
15-04-15    19-apr  937 221
16-04-15    19-apr  1013    204
17-04-15    19-apr  1263    274
18-04-15    19-apr  1055    306
19-04-15    19-apr  1173    287
20-04-15    26-apr  909 209
```

Here is a snippet of the said table (it goes all the way to 2017). The cells I would like to call the module on is Total and if possible Companytotal.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want these four steps to be in the same VBA routine or function, or do you want them to be individual steps, possibly as cell functions and the final step as a VBA routine or function? As an aside the cell function =DAY(...) will return just the day of the month for a date.

Comment: Hey! If possible, I would like all of this to be done with click of a button, but if not the. Separate functions are fine.

Comment: You have the first step of the solution, like JimmyNJ have said : the function =DAY(...). Can you continue with that? And you have : First of month, use DateSerial(year, month, 1), and for the last day in month, use DateSerial(year, month + 1, 0)

Comment: Thanks that works good! But I want to somehow select all the found cells.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the rows. In the loop, check if the date is the first day of a month. If it is, select it and activate the macro (it will then be the active cell). When the macro is executed, the loop goes on and does the same for the remaining cells.

Also, try not to write macros using ActiveCell, Select etc. It will make your life easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats answer for 3 first steps:

```
Sub tets()

i = 2
Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value <> ""
    If Day(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value) = 1 Then
       Range("F" & i).Select
       SomeMacro

    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

About your last question: ofc it is possible, but I don't understand, which columns you want to fill and what is the range (from first day of month to the last, am I right?)